# Problems with delegate creator for Jackson Databind

Tags: java, jackson

Using Jackson Databind for deserialization, I would like to override the creation (creation only, not population) of the target POJO object.  I've tried to use a custom ValueInstantiator to delegate the object creation, but Jackson does not call the creator method.  The docs are quite sparse with regards to the ValueInstantiator, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

How can I accomplish this?

Code is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a3c84b5db798b17e04c

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but perhaps looking at `StdValueInstantiator` would help. Code you have looks ok, I can not see immediate problem.
What logging output do you get?

Looking at unit tests, looks like there is just one test, and that exercises use of default constructor, not delegating one.
I can add another one and see that things work as expected -- it is quite possible this could be a simple bug too.

EDIT: there is one minor (?) problem in sample code: method specified (`create`) should take one argument; delegate `Object` being passed. Otherwise call will fail with parameter mismatch. But if you do not get an exception, it probably isn't getting called at this point.

Comment: ... for what it is worth, similar code works for me, with Jackson 2.5.1. So I don't think there is an outright bug.